# is there any start date like end date in ui-bootstrap angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to disable dates before a date.
Is there any way?Here is my code.

```
$scope.open = function($event)
{
 $event.preventDefault();
 $event.stopPropagation();
 $scope.opened = true;
};
$scope.dateOptions = {
 formatYear: 'yy',
 startingDay: 1
};
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
};
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened"  max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" style="float:left" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [angular ui bootstrap docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) :

- min-date  (Default: null) : Defines the minimum available date.
- max-date  (Default: null) : Defines the maximum available date.

Which would make your code look like :

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
 formatYear: 'yy',
 startingDay: 1,
 minDate : new Date("whatever"),
 maxDate : new Date("whatever")
};
```